# React.js state showing undefine while fetch data from the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, react-state

i am try to fetch tha data from the api, the data is geting properly but while i set the data using state eg :- const data = setUser(data), than it's showing the undefine

here is the code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// get request is placed here -------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx----------------------

function Student() {
  const [users, setUsers] =useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getStu() {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/books");
      const data = res;
      setUsers(data)
      console.log(users)
    }
    getStu();
  }, []);
```

how to solve undefined error i watch so many youtube video but nothing is working

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues here.

1. Initialise your state with the type of data you're expecting in the request whether it's an array or an object etc.
2. You can't immediately log an updated state as state updates are asynchronous and batched. Use a separate `useEffect` hook to log the state with the state listed in its dependency array.
3. Axios [returns an object with the API data as a value of the `data` property](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) so you need to extract that.

   The other properties are the status/statusText etc which you may want to inspect to check that there isn't an error with the response.

```js
function Student() {
  
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  // ---------------------------------^
  // Initialise state with an array
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getStu() {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/books");
      setUsers(res.data);
      // ---------^
      // Use the data value in the response object
    
    }
    getStu();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => console.log(users), [users]);
  // ----^
  // Add a separate `useEffect` with `users` in its
  // dependency array

...

}
```

Comment: when i try to update the data using map method it's again showing undefine

Answer (score 0):

**setState()** is an async function . using `console.log()` just right after setting the new state will render the previous value in your case undefined . To show the new state move it to another **useEffect** hook .

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(users)

}, [users])
```

be aware when using axios , you send a request to the server it returns a response, **Axios responses are  objects**.  with data , status , StatusText  , Headers  ... . if you want   the `payload that the server returned` . you have  to access  `data object` in your case  **res.data** .

In your case change your code like this  :

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getStu() {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/books");     
      setUsers(res.data)
      console.log(users)
    }
    getStu();
  }, []);
```